# View move up and move down translate animation when show and hide

Tags: android, animation

Hi I have two views in linear layout with vertical orientation as below, I want move up and move down animation when the second view is shown and hide. 
As if now when I show and hide the second imageview it works like sudden changes, i want to make it smooth transition using some animation.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_padding"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/normal_padding"
android:weightSum="2">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/b_icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_padding"
    android:src="@drawable/find_books" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tab_icon_shadow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/tab_icon_shadow"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should combine Translation & AlphaAnimation to make transition smooth.

Comment: Hi I have added  android:animateLayoutChanges="true" now it becomes smooth without adding any animation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have added android:animateLayoutChanges="true" now it becomes smooth transition without adding any animation